# What does it mean when someone says to "deliver the eyeballs"?

Tags: idioms, semantics, idiom-meaning

Skimming through the following article on [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2018/apr/17/get-rich-quick-silicon-valley-startup-billionaire-techie) I stumbled upon the following sentence:

> So if someone asked “What’s your space?” and you had a deeply unfashionable job like, say, writer, it behooved you to say “I deliver eyeballs like a fucking ninja”.

What exactly does it mean to deliver the eyeballs in this context?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It means "attract readers".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concerning the use of "eyeballs" in place of  "viewers"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/344079/concerning-the-usage-of-eyeballs-in-place-of-viewers).

Comment: Shouldn't it be deliver TO eyeballs? Otherwise you're delivering viewership. It's supposed to be I deliver to the viewership writing/articles etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When people say "deliver eyeballs like a fucking ninja," they mean, "I'm can get a quarter-million people to look at your website." Obviously, that means quite something different than carving peoples' eyes out, after which they won't be able to see any websites.

Answer (score 2):

**eyeballs** [ plural ] [Cambridge Dictionarry][1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/eyeballs)

​   > MARKETING the number of people who watch a particular television

> channel or visit a particular website:

AS IN:

> Our xyz firm will guarantee to **deliver the eyeballs** to you website
>   twice what you currently experience.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it should be _twice_ the number of viewers (or very nearly so).